# Mocking abstract super class method directly from child class

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a sub class that extends abstract class called **AbstractParentClass**
like

```
class Child extends AbstractParentClass
```

This AbstractParentClass contains a method called `getParentAbstractServiceMethod` which returns some service class object. That services class has another method called `getParentAbstractClassDomainFacade` which returns some other class object  which is not abstract and so on...This is like method chaining.

Snippet inside Child class is  as follows

```
SessionClass userSession = (SessionClass)
getParentAbstractServiceMethod().getParentAbstractClassDomainFacade().getParentAbstractClassDomainObject(SessionClass.NAME);
```

How to mock `getParentAbstractServiceMethod()` method since this is abstract class method I cannot instantiate it and call..

Answer (score 1):

The best solution was to follow the *"Favour composition over Inheritance"* principle and turn the AbstractServiceClass into a regular class that gets the current extenders as dependencies implementing an interface that provides the method to be called on them.

---

having written this the less advisable solution is to create a mock of the Abstract class using Mockito:

```
AbstractParentClass cut= Mockito.mock(AbstractParentClass.class,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
Mockito.when(cut.getParentAbstractServiceMethod()).thenAnswer(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should step back and look at your design. What is the point of testing a child class (of an abstract class) ... that doesn't implement the abstract methods in the first place.

I think you should do the following:

A) test your base class as far as possible; for example by creating a **test only** child class that somehow meaningfully implements the abstract methods

B) make sure that your "real" child classes provide reasonable implementations of your abstract methods.

And hint: consider *not* putting *abstract* into your method names. They are only abstract on the parent level; not in the childs that implement them.